# Need help in including all jar files in a directory to the existing project

Tags: java, apache, ant, build, apache-axis

I have added a piece of sharepoint code to the existing java file which was compiling and working fine. The sharepoint code that is written uses some of the external libraries. Now I need to add the external library to the existing project through ANT.

I have done a few modifications in the build.xml file and hence resolved all the compilation  errors. However when the code is getting executed, I get an Error message saying "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/entropysoft/eci/spi/IContentProviderFactory". Please help me resolving this error.

Also please let me know what needs to be added in the build.xml file to resolve the error.
All the jar files is present in the directory "externallibs"

Thanks,
Rajath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have all the jars in the classpath when running the application:

```
java -cp externallibs/* com.foo.bar.Main
```

If it's a Java EE web application, the build process should copy all these jars to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of the generated web app structure.

Comment: Please let me know How to setup a classpath?

Comment: It's in the answer: -cp externallibs/* includes all the .jar files of externallibs in the classpath. If you have another jar elsewhere, use -cp /path/to/other.jar:externallibs/*.jar. On Windows, use ; as separator instead of :, and \ instead of /.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/entropysoft/eci/spi/IContentProviderFactory` does not mean the class `net.entropysoft.eci.spi.IContentProviderFactory` is not found. It means the class that is used within this class are not found anywhere in the classpath. This error is thrown when the class loader is trying to load the class but it cannot properly initialize the class definition.

To solve this problem, you will need to look at the source code of the class `net.entropysoft.eci.spi.IContentProviderFactory`, usually at the import section, and determine what is the missing Java class and which library the missing class is in. Once you know you can add that library to your classpath using the answer by JB Nizet. If you run it from IDE, then you will need to add that library to you build.xml.